# How do I extract variable values from a route when using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am a Java Developer learning and implementing ReactJS. In Spring framework in Java we can extract a variable from the path using `@PathParam` value, I am looking for something similar for following route.

```
<Route path="/school-class/:letter/:keyword-school-class/" component={ SchoolClassContainer }/>
```

The problem I am facing is after letter, then entire word ":keyword-school-class" is considered as a param for the method call, I want only keyword to be the param. Rest should map the Route, the thing here is I can't change the routes.

The above is a sample example and not the actual code, I have modified only "school-class" rest is same.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `/school-class/:letter/(:keyword)-school-class/`?

Comment: Thanks @Maxx I am trying it right now

Comment: doesn't work it confuses this path with another path that has /school-class/:letter/:pageNumber/

Comment: It's common to use pageNumber, limit, offset and other params as query params, not as part of path

Comment: Yes @Maxx I agree with you, but somehow in my current project it doesn't seem feasible, is there any other way ?

Comment: in your case and with react router no. Your path `/school-class/:letter/:pageNumber/` matches to `/school-class/A/keyword-school-class/` for example. How can router could know that `keyword-school-class` in this example is not a pageNumber? You should modify your paths.